# Create 2 CAD files

Tags: irobot-create, design, turtlebot2

I found CAD files for the Create on the [ROS TurleBot download page](http://download.ros.org/downloads/turtlebot/) ([.zip](http://download.ros.org/downloads/turtlebot/TurtleBot-Hardware-2011-07-23.zip)),
and shells on the [gazebo sim page](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/e024fe922c810f468e2a7ab277750354465478cd/create/?at=default).

Any ideas where the files for the Create 2 could be found?

Comment: Did you try asking iRobot over email?

Comment: I asked but I got no response.

Comment: When I reach a dead end searching for CAD models I just make one myself as Steve suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CAD you pointed out is for the Turtlebot, and includes electromechanical CAD for that assembly. I only spot-checked a few files, but the only Create-relevant CAD in that package I found was an STL of the robot's outer dimensions. The Create 2 manual should have enough information for someone to produce a solid model of similar precision, but I do not believe iRobot has released a shell for the robot, yet. Maybe you should make one and put it on a site like Thingiverse? There are other designs by iRobot that can be found there for various parts of the robot, like the bin.

<sup>Please note that I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.</sup>

Comment: iRobot's Thingiverse page can be found here (http://www.thingiverse.com/irobot/designs); I imagine that if they were to release any other CAD, it would appear there, too.